# How to know the order of the labels when using flow_from_directory()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm doing multi-class classification using softmax. My final output gives me three probabilities each corresponding to one of the class, how do I know which class is each probability referring to?
I'm training my model through a image data generator.

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/gdrive/MyDrive/shot/training',
    target_size=(640, 360),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical')
```

[/gdrive/MyDrive/shot/training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfukx.png)
In the same project I'm feeding some images through test_datagen for prediction, how do I know which image the model.predict() is working on?

```
t_gen = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/gdrive/MyDrive/shot/testing',
    target_size=(640, 360),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical')

classes = model.predict(t_gen,batch_size=32)
print(classes)
```

I'm getting a table full of probabilities as answer but I don't know which image has been predicted and which label each probability corresponds to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you trained from imagedata generator, you can use your class as follow

```py
labels = list(train_datagen.class_indices.keys())
pred = model.predict(input_data)
classes = labels[pred.argmax()]

print(classes)

# or
labels = ['badshot', 'goodshot', 'noshot']
pred = model.predict(input_data)
classes = labels[pred.argmax()]
```

Comment: Could you also mention in which order does image data generator input the images. Also, 'ImageDataGenerator' object has no attribute 'class_indices'.

Comment: By right it follow the order of your image drive

Answer (score 0):

The classes will be automatically inferred from the subdirectory names/structure under directory, where each subdirectory will be treated as a different class as you did not pass in any value to the parameter `classes` as per the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdirectory-method).

So the order would be `'badshot', 'goodshot', 'noshot'` according to the image of the file directory.